# What are the correct permissions for a systemd .service?

Tags: permissions, systemd, webserver

I need to create a service for a web server called [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) I would like to know what are the correct linux permissions for this. or if exists a general rule for whatever systemd service?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Any local user can read the definition of any systemd system unit through the [DBus interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html) (for example using `systemctl show someUnitName`), unless you have a custom DBus policy in place to prevent this.

Making the unit file not world-readable thus makes no sense and systemd will print a warning if applicable. Similarly, it will also warn if the unit file is marked executable.

Unless you want the unit file to be editable for a particular (non-root) user or group, stick to the same convention used for most other system files: **0644 root:root**.

Comment: `systemd` can also manage **user** services, in which cases the definition goes into a user directory (such as `~/.config/systemd/user`) instead of `/etc/systemd`, and the owner would be the user, not root.